# SharePoint Online CSOM - file upload (overwrite) wipes all metadata when lookup threshold is exceeded

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I downloaded a file from SharePoint and modified its content. After that, I wanted to upload the updated version (see code below).
Everything works fine for most libraries - the file is updated and metadata remains untouched.
However, a problem arises when the list has many fields/columns, exceeding the lookup threshold (more than 12). In these cases, uploading wipes out all the metadata. Do you have any ideas on how to address this? I would prefer not to fetch all values and reset them.

```cs
var list = context.Web.Lists.GetById(libraryId);
var folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderRelativeUrl);

context.Load(list);
context.Load(folder);
await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();

FileCreationInformation newFile = new()
{
    ContentStream = fileStream,
    Url = fileName,
    Overwrite = true
};

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = folder.Files.Add(newFile);
context.Load(uploadFile);
await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

I tried to load the item using .ListItemAllFields before executing the file upload query. However, the item loaded in this manner had empty properties for lists with 12+ lookup columns. I considered using a CAML query to fetch field values in batches, but these fields can vary between libraries.